# Error compiling template unexpected identifier when rendering a value from a wysiwyg editor

Tags: laravel, vue.js, trix

[image]

I have few questions for you, and it's all about in the

```
@forelse ($users as $user)

    <users-view :users="{{ $user }}" inline-template/>
```

- Since I get this when I navigate to the second page of the paginated website.
  Maybe it's because of these kinds of expressions like these...

or to put it clearly these kinds of values from the wysiwyg editor.. wherein theres a  tag inside it
[image]

Comment: I recommend you to use Vuex as state management. https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: I only get this on my second paginated page.